# how to use torch.argmax and get only index value

Tags: python, pytorch, argmax

Using torch==1.7.1

MRE:

```
lst = [torch.rand(4).reshape(1,-1) for _ in range(5)]
```

for each tensor, I want to get index of largest value.

```
max_indexes = [torch.argmax(tensor) for tensor in lst]
```

which outputting

```
[tensor(0), tensor(0), tensor(2), tensor(2), tensor(2)]
```

I want to use its positions to be able to grab appropriate value from list of actions. How can I remove tensor and just get max_index?

desired output looks like this:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `[i.item() for i in max_indexes]`

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks!